# WPF - ListView with GridView - Changing properties at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I have a listview that uses a gridview to display the data. There are nine columns inside the gridview and each column (GridViewColumn) has a header (GridViewColumnHeader). There is a requirement that if the user wants to edit an item in the list, the celltemplate should change to ComboBoxes and the Margins between each control should change, which means that the column width is going to change accordingly.
The way I thought of doing this is by adding Padding Left to each of the GridViewColumnHeader and change that value in code whenever I need.
On the first run of the app the list is created correctly with the right margins however when I start changing the margins in runtime it is behaving very weird.

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_CaseLibrary" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF20212B" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource CaseLibraryListStyle}"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                              Foreground="{x:Null}" Padding="0" Margin="32,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CaseLibrary, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                      Loaded="lv_CaseLibrary_Loaded">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="gv_CaseLibrary" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyleLast}" AllowsColumnReorder="False"  >
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=cb_Selected}" Header="{x:Type CheckBox}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyleFirst}">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox x:Name="cb_Selected" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Click="cb_Selected_Click"
                                                  Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxNoText}" Margin="24,0,28,0" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=tb_PatientName}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="gvch_PatientName" Content="Patient Name" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Margin="0"/>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_PatientName" Text="{Binding PatientName}" MaxHeight="45" MaxWidth="161"
                                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                            ToolTip="{Binding PatientName}" ToolTipService.Placement="Top"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=tb_MRN}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="gvch_MRN" Content="MRN" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Padding="68,0,0,0" />
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_MRN" Text="{Binding PatientMRN}" Margin="{Binding Padding, ElementName=gvch_MRN}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=tb_DOB}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="gvch_DOB" Content="DOB" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Padding="68,0,0,0" />
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_DOB" Text="{Binding PatientDOB}" Margin="{Binding Padding, ElementName=gvch_DOB}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=tb_DateCreated}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="gvch_DateCreated" Content="Date Created" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Padding="68,0,0,0" />
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_DateCreated" Text="{Binding DateCreated}" Margin="{Binding Padding, ElementName=gvch_DateCreated}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=tb_LastModified}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="gvch_LastModified" Content="Last Modified" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Padding="68,0,0,0" />
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_LastModified" Text="{Binding LastModified}" Margin="{Binding Padding, ElementName=gvch_LastModified}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=cp_Specialty}" >
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="gvch_Specialty" Content="Medical Specialty" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Padding="68,0,0,0"/>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:Name="defaultTemplate">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp_Specialty" Content="{Binding }" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource defaultSpecialtyTemplate}" Margin="{Binding Padding, ElementName=gvch_Specialty}"/>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="cp_Specialty" Value="{StaticResource defaultSpecialtyTemplate}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="cp_Specialty" Value="{StaticResource editSpecialtyTemplate}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=tb_Physician}">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader x:Name="gvch_Physician" Content="Physician" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Padding="68,0,0,0"/>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp_Physician" Content="{Binding }" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource defaultPhysicianTemplate}" Margin="{Binding Padding, ElementName=gvch_Physician}"/>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="cp_Physician" Value="{StaticResource defaultPhysicianTemplate}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="cp_Physician" Value="{StaticResource editPhysicianTemplate}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=cp_Buttons}">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="cp_Buttons" Content="{Binding }" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource defaultButtonGrid}"/>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="cp_Buttons" Value="{StaticResource defaultButtonGrid}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="cp_Buttons" Value="{StaticResource editButtonGrid}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource defaultLVTemplate}"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFCF9F9"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Global Sans Serif"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Code Behind for changing Padding value

```
void SetPaddingForHeaders(Thickness padding)
        {
            gvch_MRN.Padding = padding;
            gvch_DOB.Padding = padding;
            gvch_DateCreated.Padding = padding;
            gvch_LastModified.Padding = padding;
            gvch_Physician.Padding = padding;
            gvch_Specialty.Padding = padding;
            AutoSizeGridViewColumns(lv_CaseLibrary);
        }

public void AutoSizeGridViewColumns(ListView listView)
        {
            GridView gridView = listView.View as GridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                foreach (var column in gridView.Columns)
                {
                    if (double.IsNaN(column.Width))
                        column.Width = column.ActualWidth;
                    column.Width = double.NaN;
                }
            }
        }
```

Wanted Behaviour:

[Designed Default View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ow2p.png)

[Designed Default Edit View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlwUz.png)

Notice how the width and margin(padding) of the column shift between the 2 modes

Current Real Behaviour (WPF):

[It starts out OK, although the padding size seems a bit off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFscy.png)

[Moving to edit mode also seems ok but again with the padding size a bit off (the last column is pushed a bit outside of the view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsoyX.png)

[And going back to default mode moves the columns even more further apart even though it's supposed to bring them closer together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3RYs.png)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "behaving weird"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought I added images showing what's needed and the current behavior. I added it to the original post. Thanks.